# Azure Websites VirtualSubFolder

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I want to know if in Azure Websites (shared) I can create a virtual subfolder of the main app. I want to do this because I want to keep some files that are created by the users safe during deployment.

Now I use IIS and I have a virtual folder that is mapped to a different directory. SO when I put a new version. (delete all and put new files) my users files are safe.

I want to know if this is possible in Azure Websites(maybe a sugestion how) ?

How would you handle this kind of scenarios ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the storage on azure can be removed unexpecdidly you should use blob storage. 
Heres where you get started: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Comment: I would also suggest using Blob Storage, but more for the reasons explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681488/migrate-azure-web-site-to-azure-cloud-service/11692581#11692581